# In Java, throwing an exception when a network connection is lost during a WebService Call (similiar to WCF CommunicationException)

Tags: java, wcf, web-services

I'm dealing with an auto-generated WebService stub in Java (generated using JAX-WS RI).

My actual service is a .Net program exposing its webservice using the WCF basicHttpBinding.

How should I be dealing with Communiction problems during the actual WebService call. (i.e. the way in WCF on the client you would wrap your call with a catch CommunicationException if communication/network problems were encountered).

It seems like there are no checked exceptions for dealing with this.

(When I view the auto-generated stub interface by web service methods don't throw an Exceptions, other then the predefined FaultExceptions/Messages exposed by WSDL).

Also, when I actually tested what would happen during a WebService call if the network was disconnected, the client simply hung on the call, instead of throwing even some sort of runtime exception.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: It appears your question is entirely regarding the Java client/stub, and has nothing to do with the WCF service at all. Is that correct?

Comment: You could use WS-ReliableMessaging to deal with such kind of problems

Comment: Yep thats what it seems like. I'm thinking the stub has to be generated differently somehow,  to expose some sort of checked exception for communication errors (like a javax.xml.soap.SOAPException).

Comment: In response to kd304, I was looking at using the WsHttpBinding instead  (on the server side) which supports reliable messaging. I'm not too well versed in the concepts of reliable messaging, but if it's turned on and the web reference is updated, will the java client be simply hang on the service call, until a connection is reestablished ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think it useful to have to deal with a communication error (e.g. due to a network failure) as a *checked* exception? How could the caller of a webservice usefully deal with such an eventuality?

It seems better to me to allow an unchecked exception to propagate up the stack until a point where it can reasonably be handled.

Comment: It could be a runtime exception as well, however in my case it seems like no exception is being thrown and the service call simply hangs. 

In a corresponding .Net WCG Client application, I can catch CommunicationExceptions and TimeOutExceptions and deal with the accordingly.